# Hi, I am trying to add specific nodes of a set to a list, the list being in a hash table

Tags: c++

I have the following set and list declarations:

```
set<mystruct> my_entries;
unordered_map<string, list<_Rb_tree_const_iterator<mystruct>>> mylist;
```

What I am trying to do is basically insert some specific nodes of the set to the list as well after inserting it into the set.

```
auto inserted = my_entries.insert(entry);
mylist[name].push_back(*inserted.first);
```

I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 
'std::list<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<mystruct> >::push_back(const 
mystruct&)’
     mylist[name].push_back(*inserted.first);
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const mylist’ to 
'std::list<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<mylist> >::value_type&& {aka 
std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<mylist>&&}'
```

Any ideas whats gone wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The underscore at the beginning of `_Rb_tree_const_iterator` should be a big red flag that this should only be used by the compiler or the standard library implementation. Where did you get it, and why are you using it?

Comment: sorry, coming from C background, I was not aware that I cannot use  _Rb_tree_const_iterator directly. I found it from the compiler error when trying to declare the list in a different way earlier. Is it possible to use C++ library to achieve what I am trying to do, or do I have to do it in C way?

Comment: @akp You should not be using names such as `_Rb_tree_const_iterator`  in C, either. They are reserved for the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments describe, you should not be attempting to use internal types from the standard library.  You can store the iterator as follows:

```
set<mystruct> my_entries;
unordered_map<string, list<set<mystruct>::const_iterator>> mylist;

// ...

mylist[name].push_back(inserted.first);
```

Whenever storing iterators, it's important to understand the rules governing when such iterators can become invalid.  In the case of [std::set::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) you are guaranteed:

> No iterators or references are invalidated.